# AWS hosted Direct Connect connect through ISP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-direct-connect

I need to have a 5 gbps Direct Connect connection to my Amazon VPC from my servers residing at a ISP data-centre.

I can't wait for more than 1 week to set it up. Is it possible through a hosted Direct Connect connection to get the 5 gbps?

Answer (score 4):

According to the AWS documentation about hosted Direct connect, you can only have sub 1G connection through your ISP.

Answer (score 4):

Well you need to contact one of their APNs to know more about it !!!